# Use integer64 as a key with data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a column of `integer64` and would like to use that as the key, only it does not work as shown below: the value gives `NA`.

**This works**

```
s = data.table(id=1000000107000008595, value=10)
setkey(s, id)
s[J(1000000107000008595)]
#             id value
# 1: 1.00000e+18    10
```

**This does not work**

```
s = data.table(id=as.integer64(1000000107000008595), value=10)
setkey(s, id)
s[J(1000000107000008595)]
#             id value
# 1: 1.00000e+18    NA  # <- NA is the problem
```

Comment: It's essential to provide the version number in these sort of questions. Also it'd be nice if you could add the libraries you've loaded to your code so that it's easy to copy/paste (or `sessionInfo()`).

Answer (score 3):

What version of R. packages are you using?
I just tried this:

```
library(bit64)
library(data.table)
s = data.table(id=1000000107000008595, value=10)
setkey(s, id)
s[J(1000000107000008595)]

s = data.table(id=as.integer64(1000000107000008595), value=10)
setkey(s, id)
s[J(1000000107000008595)]
```

and it gives me

```
> s = data.table(id=1000000107000008595, value=10)
> setkey(s, id)
> s[J(1000000107000008595)]
      id value
1: 1e+18    10
> 
> s = data.table(id=as.integer64(1000000107000008595), value=10)
> setkey(s, id)
> s[J(1000000107000008595)]
                    id value
1: 1000000107000008576    10
```

Im on

```
> version$version.string
[1] "R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)"
```

and `sessionInfo()` says

```
other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.6 bit64_0.9-5      bit_1.1-12
```